# Where do i find the Vuetify theme color variable definitions?

Tags: vuejs3, vuetifyjs3

I know you can create custom themes, but I was curious how to get theme colors for the standard 'light' and 'dark' themes and a list of available variables? I want to use some of the colors in SVGs, and aside from I guess encapsulating the SVGs within a v-container or something which might achieve the same result, I was hoping to find the exact colour.

I "pretty much" answered my own question when I found .\node_modules\vuetify\dist\vuetify.css gives the theme colours for every component, eg:

```
.v-card--variant-elevated, .v-card--variant-flat {
  background: rgb(var(--v-theme-surface));
  color: rgba(var(--v-theme-on-surface), var(--v-high-emphasis-opacity));
}
```

... and this ended up solving my problem as I could use `background-color: rgba(var(--v-theme-surface));` to achieve my goal of mimicking the same colour from a v-card in my page.

I also found the following code below which seems pretty interesting and might explain why I can't find the actual Variable-to-RGB mapping anywhere as this appears (in my beginner/layman eyes) to generate them dynamically?

.\node_modules\vuetify\lib\composables\theme.mjs:

```
  167      for (const key of colors) {
  168        if (/^on-[a-z]/.test(key)) {
  169:         createCssClass(fgLines, `.${key}`, [`color: rgb(var(--v-theme-${key})) !important`]);
  170        } else {
  171:         createCssClass(bgLines, `.bg-${key}`, [`--v-theme-overlay-multiplier: var(--v-theme-${key}-overlay-multiplier)`, `background: rgb(var(--v-theme-${key})) !important`, `color: rgb(var(--v-theme-on-${key})) !important`]);
  172:         createCssClass(fgLines, `.text-${key}`, [`color: rgb(var(--v-theme-${key})) !important`]);
  173:         createCssClass(fgLines, `.border-${key}`, [`--v-border-color: var(--v-theme-${key})`]);
  174        }
  175      }
  ...
  268    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(theme.colors)) {
  269      const rgb = parseColor(value);
  270:     variables.push(`--v-theme-${key}: ${rgb.r},${rgb.g},${rgb.b}`);
  271      if (!key.startsWith('on-')) {
  272:       variables.push(`--v-theme-${key}-overlay-multiplier: ${getLuma(value) > 0.18 ? lightOverlay : darkOverlay}`);
  273      }
  274    }
  ...
  276      const color = typeof value === 'string' && value.startsWith('#') ? parseColor(value) : undefined;
  277      const rgb = color ? `${color.r}, ${color.g}, ${color.b}` : undefined;
  278:     variables.push(`--v-${key}: ${rgb ?? value}`);
  279    }
  280    return variables;
```

So question: is there a "vuetify theme variable to RGB" mapping somewhere, or if it's using the code above (or something similar) I could maybe use that to generate a list of variables and associated RGB values (if I wasn't a beginner!) ChatGPT gives a "pretty good" mapping but suspect they're from Vue2 as it references a bunch of files that arn't there anymore: it mentions everything can be found in colors.scss, but that seems to use a functon called "map-get" to perhaps lookup the RGB...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `createVuetify()` to register the extension with Vue, the theme is created from the options you pass in merged with a default theme (see [`createVuetify()`](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/framework.ts#L48) and [`createTheme()`](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/composables/theme.ts#L203)). The default theme values can be found [here](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/composables/theme.ts#L108).

During runtime, you can access color values through the [`useTheme()`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/use-theme/) composable (or from the vuetify instance created by `createVuetify()`):

```js
vuetify.theme.current.value.colors
useTheme().current.value.colors
```

This will give you an object mapping color name to color value:

```js
{
  background: "#FFFFFF",
  surface: "#FFFFFF", 
  "surface-variant": "#424242",
  "on-surface-variant": "#EEEEEE",
  primary: "#6200EE",
  "primary-darken-1": "#3700B3",
  secondary: "#03DAC6",
  "secondary-darken-1": "#018786",
  error: "#B00020",
  info: "#2196F3",
  ...
}
```

Toggle the theme in the snippet to see the values change:

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;
const { createVuetify, useTheme } = Vuetify
const vuetify = createVuetify()
const app = {
  setup(){
    const theme = useTheme()
    const toggleTheme = () => theme.global.name.value = theme.global.current.value.dark ? 'light' : 'dark'
    return {
      currentTheme: theme.current,
      toggleTheme,
    }
  }

}
createApp(app).use(vuetify).mount('#app')
```

```css
.swatch{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.v-theme--dark .swatch{
  border-color: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.8/dist/vuetify.min.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-btn @click="toggleTheme">toggle theme</v-btn>
      
      <v-table density="compact">
        <template #default>
          <thead>
            <tr><th>Name</th><th>Color</th></tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr v-for="(color, name) in currentTheme.colors" :key="name">
              <td>{{ name }}</td>
              <td><div class="swatch" :style="{background: color}"></div>{{ color }}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </template>
      </v-table>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.8/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
```

Is that the kind of map you were looking for?